# Fitting a logarithmic trendline on already logged values

Tags: analysis, logarithms, regression, variance, percentages

This is the situation. I am running trials with a population simulator, which produces various outputs, with the variance of these outputs being dependent on the number of clones (recursions) the simulator has gone through.

Generally speaking, the higher the cloning; the lower the variance. My task is to prove this relationship. So my variables are x = # of clones (let's say 0 to 10), and y = total population. So far I've done several tests pertaining to things like %change between each x, and distance from the mean of each x, etc. to show the relationship, and now I would like to do the ln differences.

**MY QUESTION IS: On Excel, would plotting the ln of y against x, then adding the "Logarithmic Trendline" option make sense?** The log trendline seems to fit my data the best (for obvious reasons), and I was planning to take the distance from each (x,**y**) to the trendline equation to have %values to show the relationship I am trying to prove. But I'm wondering if this makes mathematical sense. I know that plotting the ln of y with x with a *linear trendline* makes sense, similar in the way that plotting non-logged y with x with a *logarithmic trendline* makes sense, but I'm kind of stumped as to justifying why fitting a logarithmic trendline on already-logged values of y makes sense (even though it makes for the best graph).

Should I continue with my idea or should I be content with simply plotting plotting ln y with x with a linear trendline to show the relationship?

***EDIT

[#1. This is what I have and what makes mathematical sense to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FApSi.png)

[#2. This is what I want to use (but not sure if it makes sense)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Veadd.png)

***essentially, I am wondering if option #2 would result in mathematically-useful value for analysis, or would I just be analyzing mathematical nonsense?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of what you are doing makes sense. You are trying to fit "noise" and any model you will try will be as bad/useless as any other.

The best model: $$y=17.4$$

Comment: That is indeed what I am trying to do.... I am trying to build a model to compare the different levels of this "noise" between tests (because we are trying to select an x by seeing at which x we should start seeing less and less noise).

Could you please explain why would a y-value of 17.4 be the best model? Is that an approximation or does it have mathematical significance?

Comment: @GabeMath: it is obvious that trying to fit a monotonic curve to this data makes no sense. Apparently, not to you.

Comment: @GabeMath: at the data has no obvious trend and has a tiny coefficient of variation, a constant is good enough.

Comment: Dauost: Actually yes, the general trend seems to be that the y values seem to stabilize towards a certain value the higher the x value (the more cloning that occurs).

But how would I go about choosing this constant? Should I just choose y-mean as the comparison?

Comment: @GabeMath: without outliers, mean, with outliers, median.